# What scenes from each Heroine's route must have happened, considering the storyline of Meikyuu and Rakuen of Grisaia?

Tags: grisaia

In the second and third VN, they ditched the heroine's routes, but some elements were used. So, excluding the H scenes, what other scenes/events must have happened alongside with the common route, to explain the storyline of Rakuen and Meikyuu?

For example:

> Makina learning how to operate a sniper rifle.